# Java InputStream Downloading Slowly

Tags: java, performance, download

I am using this code to download an encrypted file:

```
InputStream frame = new URL(url).openStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int count;
byte[] buff = new byte[10000];
while((count = frame.read(buff)) > 0){
    data.write(buff, 0, count);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

This code works great sometimes, but others it can take up to a minute for a ~36 kilobyte file. Is there a better way of doing this or is the problem simply the connection to the download server?

Comment: @Skizo Why? The only way `read()` can return zero is if `buff` is zero length, and it isn't.

Comment: @DiscountPort The code is fine. The server or the connection is the problem. I would remove the `println()` from inside the loop though. I would also avoid using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as an intermediary, and process the data immediately as it is received: otherwise you're adding latency and wasting space.

Comment: I am guessing that someone named Skizo suggested reading until `-1` instead of `0`. While the documentation for `InputStream.read` seems to indicate that `0` will not be returned, I have seen, in certain exception cases, `0` be returned and the subsequent `read` call throw an `IOException`. This may well be an incorrect `InputStream` implementation, but I have found checking for `-1` to be safer.

Comment: @BrettOkken He suggested testing `> -1` instead of `> 0`. I haven't seen what you described at any time since 1997, but if the subsequent read call throws `IOException` it is still therefore valid to test `> 0`. I generally use `> -1` myself: my point was that the suggested change was unmotivated.

Comment: @EJP, if you stop when you get `0` and the next call (which does not get made) would have thrown an exception, you believe that all the content has been read when it has not.

Comment: The reason I need to process it all at once is it is encrypted and compressed, so I need to decrypt it and decompress it as a whole.